# Is it possible to compile a block of code only for a certain target (Android app)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'd like to understand what is the best approach to execute a block of code that it is only necessary on Debug target, on a certain activity, without being dependent on 'if' statements. Also, if it's possible to exclude the block of code from compilation when compiling the same app for another target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, the best and easiest approach would be to do the following which will only execute in debuggable apps:

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  // run your piece of code
}
```

If you use proguard on your release it will be stripped along with any other dead code from your app as it will evaluate to "false" for release builds. This is the easy way.

---

> without being dependent on 'if' statements

In this case you need to create 2 versions of your class, one in your `app/src/release` and one in your `app/src/debug` folder. This makes use of resource merging offered by gradle, where you combine multiple source sets into one. If you were to put one in `/main` and one in `/debug` it wouldn't compile as you'd have a duplicate class, so be sure to define one class per build type (or go even further and add your own folders to certain build types if some reuse the same code...)

```
// in /release

class MyThing() {

  void doStuff() { /* nothing */ }
}


// in /debug

class MyThing() {

  void doStuff() { 
    actual();
    code();
  }
}
```

Now you can call `new MyThing().doStuff()` from your Activity and it will a) do nothing in release and b) do something in debug. I have shown an example where you would put solely the logic inside a duplicated class, but it would also be possible to just duplicate the whole activity that should execute the code...leading to...

The biggest problem with this approach is the duplication of code. Android Studio does not support refactoring with multiple source sets, so you would be switching between build types a lot. There will be build errors every once in a while because you forgot to fix something in one of the sources, and it's just a real pain.

You will effectively have to maintain all the code you duplicate in this fashion twice and you should keep the files affected to a bare minimum (for your own sake).

I would strongly recommend to use `BuildConfig.DEBUG` and not worry too much about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with flavors, in the same level as the folder 'main' create a folder called 'debug' and add a  '/java' in that, create your debug only file classes here, but to use those files within main without release erros you will need to create the same structure calling release/java and add a blank implementation of some class.